# Orientation preserving diffeomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

I am stuck with the question. I guess that I need to write jacobian matrix. But I could not do. Please help me thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If $F \colon (N,[\omega_N]) \to (M, [\omega_M]) $ is an *orientation-preserving* diffeomorphism what can you say about $F^* \omega_M$? *Hint.* You get some condition on the determinant of a Jacobi matrix.
2. Knowing the property of the determinant, use now **the chain rule** to ensure that the transition maps between charts in the atlas on $N$ that you obtain satisfy the requirements for this new atlas to be *oriented*.

---

**Edit:** The above is an attempt to stimulate some thinking on the problem. More specifically, one needs to have all the definitions handy in order to see that it is actually *much easier* than it seems to be at the first sight. Apparently, this question has been [duplicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388549/), so we now have some more information on the necessary background :-)

Now let me present a more elaborated answer.

This question is to solve Problem 20.3 from **L.Tu** "Introduction to Manifolds", p.209.

The key concept for this problem is when an atlas *specifies* the orientation on an oriented manifold. This notion is explained in the bottom of p. 207 of the cited textbook. I shall try to rephrase this in my own words.

**Definition**. An atlas $\{ (V_{\alpha}, \psi_{\alpha} ) \}_{\alpha \in A} $ specifies the [orientation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386987/) $[\omega_M]$ of an oriented manifold $(M, [\omega_M])$ if 
$$
\psi_{\alpha}^* \epsilon^n \in [\omega_M |_{V_{\alpha}}]
$$
for each $\alpha \in A$, where $\epsilon^n$ is the *standard Euclidean volume form*, that is
$$
\epsilon^n := \mathrm{d} r^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d} r^n
$$
and $\omega_M |_{V_{\alpha}}$ is the restriction of a form $\omega_M$ onto $V_{\alpha}$.

(Functions $r^i$ here are the standard Euclidean coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$)

In the problem we are asked to show that the atlas $\{ (U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}) \}_{\alpha \in A}$ on manifold $N$, constructed so that $U_{\alpha} := F^{-1} V_{\alpha}$ and $\phi_{\alpha} := \psi_{\alpha} \circ F$ for each $\alpha \in A$, specifies the orientation $[F^* \omega_N]$ on $M$.

This brings us very close to the solution. I must stop here as this question is tagged as a homework, but really one needs just check that we have some *everywhere positive functions* involved.

In particular, there is **no need to check Jacobians**!

Comment: Hmm I understand what i need to do. But these are so complicated. Please can you show me more clear. Please