# Orientation-preserving diffeomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image][image]

Can you help for solving this please. Although I study this subject I could not solve this question please help me ı am willing to learn this question.